# Which technology can we use when developing a web service?

Tags: android, wcf, web-services

I wonder if there is a technology to use instead of another one in order to develop a web service for an Android Application.

I'll develop an Android application and a website using Java Server Faces technology.

My friend and I would like to create a web service that will be used by the android application to access datas in our SQL Server Database.

I am planning to develop this web service using Windows Communication Foundation technology because it's the easiest way for me. But concerning performances, is it a good idea ? Should I use another technology to create my web service ? We plan to develop IOS and Windows Phone application that will use our web service too.

Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are looking at a large scope of developing several applications it is much more wiser to have an opensource approach . My Advice to you is if your webservice is a small scale one go for PHP  or else you can use Java as well. If you develop the Web service in a RESTful manner it is much more easy to intergrate with different platforms such as Android , iOS, WP7/8.

As you are interested in developing using WCF it is possible to develop RESTfull webservice using WCF please reffer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd315413.aspx

Comment: I have read the article and I understand that developping Web Service in a RESTfull manner is the best way in that case. I'll follow your advice. Otherwise, what about security, some people think that RESTfull is less secure than soap. What is your opinion ?

Comment: HTTPS approach is recommended you can even try this http://www.berenddeboer.net/rest/authentication.html